# De Moivre's theorem and series in complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

I came across this question from an old past paper where no solutions were provided; I only need guidance and I will give it a go...

Given that $w_n=3^{(-n)} \cos⁡2nθ$ [(for n=1,2,3….〗Use De Moivre’s theorem to show that
$$1 + w_{1} + w_2 + \cdots + w_{(n-1)} = \frac{(9 - 3 \cos2\theta + 3^{(-n-1)} \cos 2⁡(n-1)\theta-3^{(-n-1)} \cos2n\theta)}{(10 - 6 \cos 2\theta)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $w_n$ is the real part of the complex number $z_n = (3)^{-n} (\cos(2n \theta) + i \sin(2n \theta))$. So $1 + w_1 \ldots + w_{n-1}$ is the real part of $1 + z_1 + \ldots + z_{n-1}$.

Comment: A great hint, I should be there soon, thanks.

Comment: could there be a binomial expansion part in this?

Comment: I don't think there is an obvious way to drag the binomial expansion into this. Try to think of another famous identity after having applied De Moivre's theorem.

Comment: Is this the key ? Re (z + 1/z) = 2cos (x)

Comment: It wasn't what I had in mind but it may help. If you let $a = \frac{1}{3} (\cos(2\theta) + i \sin(2\theta))$, how does $1 + z_1 + \ldots + z_{n-1}$ look ?

Comment: Great. We do have a GP now in a, its sum looks good but has a power n on cos 2x, right?

Comment: Well it has a power $n$ on $a$, so you can tidy it up a bit and then use De Moivre's theorem once again to pull $n$ back in the argument of $\cos$.

Comment: There is still an issue with the denominator but am working on it.

Comment: You're probably able to fix it, just remember that you want to take the real part of a quotient of complex numbers.